# I need help creating a macro to change my default image settings

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

My most often used wrap and image settings in Microsoft Word are:

- Select Layout options
- Select 'through' layout
- Click on the more tab
- Set horizontal to relative to page
- Set vertical to relative to page
- Uncheck move object with text
- Check allow overlap

Is there a way to make a macro to do this? It is very tedious to do it over and over and over again.

Sure would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to create a macro for a beginner would be to use the Record Macro button on the Developer tab.

## To enable the developer tab

1. Click on **File**, then click on **Options**,
2. From the **Word Options** pop-up window click on **Customize Ribbon**,
3. From the **Main Tabs** window check the Developer checkbox, click **OK**

[image: gif showing how to enable Developer Tab]

## To record a macro

1. Click on the **Developer Tab**, click on **Record Macro** button,
   [image: gif showing initial recording macro step]
2. Name your macro, Give your macro a description (eg what it does),
3. Assign the macro to a button **or** to a keyboard shortcut,

   > **Note**: Once this window closes your macro will begin recording any buttons/keys you press.
4. Do any actions you need for the macro to do,
5. To stop recording, go back into the **Developer Tab** and click **Stop Recording** button.

   > **Tip**: You can also click the stop recording icon located at the bottom of the main window (refer to below image).

   [image: Stop Recording Icon]
6. Test out your macro by using the button or keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Hi angelofdev  how can i contact you?  i understand 'record macro' but when i do that it will not let me select the image...