# Is it possible to enter a value into an Excel cell and have the same cell output a result?

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image: Image 1]

Basically I want to be able to input the pay rate (ex: enter "14" to symbolize 14 dollars per hour) into the cell that already has a formula to get a result (In the same cell.).

If I input 14 in `D20` I'll get `2426.67` as the result.

The formula is `(((inputed value) * (40) * (52)) / (12))`

- 40 weekly hours
- 52 is weeks in a year
- 12 is monthly

Is it possible?

Comment: Only if you build a macro that does the calculation, The formula and the result can't exist in the cell and not be overwritten by input

Answer (score 1):

It is possible only with using VBA and listening out for the the [Worksheet_Change](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) Event.

Give the below code a try, I have added informative comments in hopes you will learn how it works.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' The below If statement uses Intersect to check, 
    ' if the cell being changed is NOT cell D20 it gets ignored.
    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("D20")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False 'Disables events to prevent endless loop

        On Error GoTo Finalise 'Re-enable events

        ' The below code gets the value from cell D20,
        ' and stores the value to the inputVal variable.
        inputVal = Range("D20").Value 

        ' The below code does your calculation, 
        ' and stores the value to the newValue variable.
        newValue = (inputVal * 40 * 52) / 12 

        'Changes the value in cell D20 to the value of the newValue variable. 
        Range("D20").Value = newValue 
    End If

Finalise:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

> **Note**: This code has to go into the sheet itself and not in a module.

**Edit**: Steps from comment.

1. Go into the **[Developer Tab](https://superuser.com/a/1402054/907112)**.
2. Click on **Visual Basic** button to open,
3. In the Visual Basic window that pops up look at the **Project - VBAProject** pane (on the left side of the window),
4. Find your Worksheet, double click on it,
5. Paste the above code in, save your workbook.

[image: Steps from comment]

Comment: I am sorry, how would I do the above? Go to macros and record ? or use relative references?

Comment: You'll have to open **Visual Basic** from the **[Developer Tab](https://superuser.com/a/1402054/907112)**. In the Visual Basic window that pops up look at the **Project - VBAProject** pane (on the left side of the window) and find your Worksheet, double click on it, then paste your code in there.

Answer (score 1):

MS Excel doesn't work that way. Once you input something in to the cell, it overwrites it's contents.

You may be able to write a macro to do this, as suggested by @datatoo, however you still have the issue of the cell changing values when the answer is determined, which may trigger another calculation.

Why do you want to do this? Maybe we can suggest an alternate method for you.

Comment: The only reason for doing this was to keep it clean and simple. I am a mortgage lender and I made this application to pre qualify clients however not all of my other loan officers are tech savvy

Comment: For that use case, this is the opposite of what you want to do. You want to put your user inputs in separate fields with explanation written next to them, then write your calculations in separate fields. Then protect the sheet, then unprotect ONLY the cells with input fields, then and only then distribute the workbook to your users. Speaking as someone who has worked with many non 'tech savvy' users of spreadsheets I've designed, the LAST thing you want to do is blur the lines between where your users are allowed to type and where they must leave things alone.

Answer (score 1):

Any cell can have either a Formula or a Value, not both, This is how basically the Excel works for.

Now to attain what you describe, you would need VBA (Macro) to do the calculation when the cell value is changed.

*The VBA code I'm suggesting in bit improvised and it works on entire Column or on any particular Data range, rather than only on a Cell, also prevents from Non numeric data.*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

 If Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
 If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then

   Application.EnableEvents = False
     Target = (Target * 40 * 52) / 12
      Application.EnableEvents = True
 Else
         MsgBox ("Only calculate numeric values")
 End If

End Sub
```

**N.B.**

- Copy & Paste this Code as Standard module.
- `Range("A:A")` is editable and should `Rage("A:C")` or even `Range("A1:C10")` also.