# Excel VBA Worksheet change, entering a range instead of one cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I found a great answer to a previous question provided by [@angelofdev](https://superuser.com/users/907112/angelofdev)
to a problem of exchanging the user entered data with the result of a formula,[HERE](https://superuser.com/questions/1402925/is-it-possible-to-enter-a-value-into-an-excel-cell-and-have-the-same-cell-output). The code works perfectly, but I am a little stuck. I tried commenting on that thread, but thought this might be better?

I need to apply this to a range of cells, e.g. `(D1:D20)`, but if I enter this into his code, it doesn't work and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong?

The code is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' The below If statement uses Intersect to check, 
    ' if the cell being changed is NOT cell D1 it gets ignored.
    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("D1")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False 'Disables events to prevent endless loop

        On Error GoTo Finalise 'Re-enable events

        ' The below code gets the value from cell D1,
        ' and stores the value to the inputVal variable.
        inputVal = Range("D1").Value 

        ' The below code does your calculation, 
        ' and stores the value to the newValue variable.
        newValue = inputVal * 0.58

        'Changes the value in cell D1 to the value of the newValue variable. 
        Range("D1").Value = newValue 
    End If

Finalise:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over the cells in the `Intersection`:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cell As Range, Intr As Range
    Set Intr = Intersect(Target, Range("D1:D20"))

    If Not Intr Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            For Each cell In Intr
                cell.Value = 0.58 * cell.Value
            Next cell
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

You don't need an intermediate variable.  Include error-catcher if you think it is necessary.

Comment: This works perfectly thank you!