# Changing VALUE in a cell on entering specific text with VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, cells

I tried to modify [this code](https://superuser.com/questions/1402925/is-it-possible-to-enter-a-value-into-an-excel-cell-and-have-the-same-cell-output) but I've got some issues with it. Every time I try to enter my text on the cell it's changing the previous cell.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("D3:D300")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False 'Disables events to prevent endless loop

    On Error GoTo Finalise 'Re-enable events

    inputVal = Range("D3:D300").Value

    newValue = "=VLOOKUP(E3,$Q$2:$R$150,2,0)"

    Range("D3:D300").Value = newValue
End If

Finalise:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

[image: Table1]

[image: Table2]

The code is working and it is changing number 44 to a name "Guy2" in the same cell, but when I go to the next row and try to enter a new value it delete the previous one. Can someone show me how to make my new value to stay in the cell even when I enter a new value on the next row?

Thank you

Comment: what is in E3?  Is it a formula that refers to D3, If so you are creating a circular reference.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Are you entering `44` in D3 and wanting it to change to `Guy2`?

Comment: Yes, I am entering 44 in D3. E3 is refering to D3 (=D3) and taking this number 44. Then the VBA is changing D3 to VLOOKUP formula that is looking for the number in E3 (44) to my table. Then it is changing the VALUE in D3 to Guy2 from the table. My point here is to change the Badge to the workers with their name instead of number and I do not want to be shown in another call, because I have 8 more columns with the same badge entering and I want the whole table to fit on the screen. I hope I explained everything good :) Column E will be hidden.

Comment: Then you cannot put a formula in the cell. You will need to do the lookup in vba and return the actual value.

Comment: Can I make the formula to stop E3 after a value is shown or something and not to take the new value from the D3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a circular reference by putting a formula in D3.  Do the lookup in vba and return just the value:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("D3:D300")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False 'Disables events to prevent endless loop

    On Error GoTo Finalise 'Re-enable events

    Target.Value = Application.VLookup(Target.Value, Me.Range("Q:R"), 2, False)
End If

Finalise:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: WOW.. you are the BEST!!! It is working now :) Thank you.

Comment: @Bonch,, since this code is working then now it's your turn to appreciate the efforts in terms of Accepting as Answer [Check this,,](https://superuser.com/tour) ,as well Up vote !

Comment: It's working @Scott Craner ,, +1 ☺